# Basic use of classes to perform basic quantitative biology

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that performs basic quantitative biology operations.  I have two separate files, a .h and .cpp.  The .h contains my class with function prototypes and my .cpp contains my function definitions.  I feel like I wrote the code correctly but it won't compile.  Here is my code:

```
//.h file

#ifndef __JMCREADY_QUBIENGINE_H_
#define __JMCREADY_QUBIENGINE_H_
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class QubiEngine{
private:
   vector<string> dna;
public:
   QubiEngine();                    //Default constructor
   QubiEngine(ifstream& dnaFile);       //Reads lines from given input file and pushes every read DNA sequence into the dna vector.
   void dna2rna();              //Reads the DNA from the dna vector and computes it's RNA, then stores them in a file rna.txt
   void compute_revcom();           //Reads the DNA sequences from the dna vector, computes the reverse, and stores in revcom.txt
   void nucl_frequency();           //Counts the total occurances of each nucleotide in the DNA sequence.
   int count_CpG();             //Counts the occurance of the string "CG"
   bool isPalindromic();                //Checks if the string is palindromic.

};

#endif
//.cpp file

#include "jmcready_QubiEngine.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <iterator>
  using namespace std;

  QubiEngine::QubiEngine(ifstream& dnaFile){
    string neucleotides;                    //Declares an empty string of nucelotides,
                                        //opens the file to be stored into the vector,
    while (getline(dnaFile, neucleotides)){ //and while it is reading the whole line from the
       dna.push_back(neucleotides);     //dnaFile, it is pushing the nucelotides into the vector.
   }
  }


 void QubiEngine::dna2rna(){
   ofstream outfile;
   outfile.open("rna.txt");         //Creates a blank text file
   const char* foo = "t";
   for (vector<string>::iterator it = dna.begin(), endOfString = dna.end(); it != endOfString; it++){
    if ( find(dna.begin(), dna.end(), foo) != dna.end() ){              //for loop with a nested if statement to run through each
        dna.at(*foo) = "u";                  //member of the vector and check if the iterator is equal
        outfile << *it;             //to "t", if it is, it is changed to "u."
    }                               //Then saves the new iterator value to the outfile.
}
 outfile.close();               //Closes the file so no further changes can be made.
}

void QubiEngine::compute_revcom(){
char letter = '\0';

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ("revcom.txt");            //Another blank text file.
vector<string> temp;                //A dummy blank vector to store the reverse of the dna vector.
reverse( dna.begin(), dna.end() );  //Stores the reverse of vector dna to temp vector.
               for (vector<string>::iterator it = temp.begin(), endOfString = temp.end(); it != endOfString; it++){
                   while ( it != dna.end() ){       //For loop with nested while loop to change
                       switch(letter){              //each element in the temp vector to it's complement element.
                           case 'a' :
                               *it = "t";
                               break;
                           case 't' :
                               *it = "a";
                               break;
                           case 'c' :
                               *it = "g";
                               break;
                           case 'g' :
                               *it = "c";
                               break;
                           default :
                               cout << "File contains elements that aren't valid, please fix."<< endl;
                               break;
                       }
                   }
  }
  outfile.close();
}

 void QubiEngine::nucl_frequency(){
int numOfA = 0;             //Declares multiple counts and letters
    int numOfT = 0;             //to keep track of each nucleotide seperately
    int numOfC = 0;
    int numOfG = 0;
    string a = "a";
    string t = "t";
    string c = "c";
    string g = "g";

    for (vector<string>::iterator it = dna.begin(), endOfString = dna.end(); it != endOfString; it++){
        if (*it == a){              //For loop with multiple nested if statements
                numOfA++;                   //to check each individual element
            }                       //and count it towards the total.
            if(*it == t){
                    numOfT++;
            }
            if (*it == c){
                    numOfC++;
            }
            if (*it == g){
                    numOfG++;
            }
    }
 }

int QubiEngine::count_CpG(){

int count = 0;
    string CpG = "cg";

    for (vector<string>::iterator it = dna.begin(), endOfString = dna.end(); it != endOfString; it++){
        if (*it == CpG){                //For loop with nested if statement to check
                count++;                    //for the string "cg" and add them to an int
            }                       //counter.
    }

    return count;
}


bool QubiEngine::isPalindromic(){

for (vector<string>::iterator it = dna.begin(), endOfString = dna.end(); it != endOfString; it++){

    if(*it == string(dna.rbegin(), dna.rend())){        //For loop with nested if statement
                return true;
            }                                //to check if *it is equal to
            else{
                    return false;
            }                            //the reverse of it's original,
                                                    //if it is equal than it is palindromic.
                   }
}



int main (int args, char* argv[]) {         //Main function given in the pdf, calls each

ifstream dnaFile;                   //public function to check if it works, and how
    dnaFile.open("dna.txt");

    QubiEngine qbengine(dnaFile);               //effectively.
    qbengine.dna2rna();

    qbengine.compute_revcom();

    qbengine.nucl_frequency();

    int cpg = qbengine.count_CpG();
    cout << "The total number of CG islands is : " << cpg << endl;

    if ( qbengine.isPalindromic() )
        cout << "Palindromic" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not Palindromic" << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

EDIT: I've managed to fix as many mistakes as I can. The only thing left are a few compiler errors, was hoping if someone can give me some tips.  The errors are in the comments at the bottom

Comment: what compilation error do you get?

Comment: "It won't compile" is absolutely meaningless, since you included no information about the compiler errors. This is not a site for dumping a bunch of code, saying "it won't compile", and expecting us to figure out what might be wrong. You have the specific information from the compiler, including error messages and the line numbers of the lines causing the problems. We don't.

Comment: @KenWhite I would have posted the errors but there are so many, I didn't think you would want to see.  Most of them are about failed conversions.

Comment: @jessemcready Seeing the errors makes it much easier to work out what is wrong, please post them if you would like us to help.

Comment: The compiler errors exceed the maximum number of characters you can have.

Comment: In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:54:0,
                 from jmcready_QubiEngine.h:19:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h: In instantiation of ‘static void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_copy_chars(_CharT*, _Iterator, _Iterator) [with _Iterator = std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’:

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:142:6:   required from ‘static _CharT* std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_construct(_InIterator, _InIterator, const _Alloc&, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _FwdIterator = std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:1722:56:   required from ‘static _CharT* std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_construct_aux(_InIterator, _InIterator, const _Alloc&, std::__false_type) [with _InIterator = std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:1743:58:   required from ‘static _CharT

Comment: * std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_construct(_InIterator, _InIterator, const _Alloc&) [with _InIterator = std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:231:55:   required from ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Alloc&) [with _InputIterator = std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string

Comment: <char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > > >; _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
jmcready_QubiEngine.cpp:122:44:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:384:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::char_traits<char>::assign(char&, std::basic_string<char>&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:384:6: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:42:0,
                 from jmcready_QubiEngine.h:19:

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:244:7: note: static void std::char_traits<char>::assign(std::char_traits<char>::char_type&, const char_type&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:244:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const char_type& {aka const char&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:276:7: note: static std::char_traits<char>::char_type* std::char_traits<char>::assign(std::char_traits<char>::char_type*, std::size_t, std::char_traits<char>::char_type)

Comment: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:276:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided

Answer (score 1):

In `QubiEngine::QubiEngine(ifstream& dnaFile)` don't do

`dnaFile("dna.txt");`

It's already initialized (in `main`) and it's not the right sintax anyway.

In `dna2rna` `*it` is a `string` so in `*it == 't'` you try to compare a `string` with a `char`. It won't work but you already know how to fix this: you use `string::iterator` elsewhere, use it to iterate through all the `char` in the string and compare `char` with `char`.

In `compute_revcom` you never initialize `letter` but you use it in a `switch`, use `st`.
You also don't advance the `string::iterator` in the `while`. You also need to use `'t'` instead of `"t"`, one is a `char`, the other is a string.

In `nucl_frequency` again you compare a a `string` with a `char`, use `string::iterator`.

In `count_CpG` you forget the type of `dna`, it's a vector of strings, use the proper iterator type. Also, `*it == CpG` will compare two strings for equality which is not what you want.

If `*it` is "cgcg" you want the count to be 2 but it will actually be 0. See if you can use `string::iterator` for this task.

Also

```
vector<string>& temp = dna;            //A dummy blank vector to store the reverse of the dna vector.
```

because of that "&" it won't do what you think, `temp` will be `dna` (exactly) and not a copy.

There are tonnes more probably.

Try not to write everything at once and build at the end. Instead, write a function, or part of a function and build (and test) that.

Move from a small program that compiles and works to a slightly larger program that compiles and works. Repeat until done!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems like it would work much better than building it at the end. Ill implement your tips.

Comment: one last thing, I fixed up the program but there's one problem I don't know how to fix.  In the main function the line ifstream dnaFile; it says "Unexpected type name 'ifstream': expected expression."  Any quick fix to this?

Comment: @jessemcready In the file containing `main` do you `#include <fstream>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `#include <fstream>` to your header file, it seems that you are missing it (for `ifstream`)

And, actually, try to move `main` into separate file, like main.cpp, in which just  `#include "jmcready_QubiEngine.h"`, *without* .cpp